# pandas: df.to_csv() creates AttributeError

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, attributeerror

I'm trying to export a pandas dataframe with df.to_csv(), which should be easy enough. Unfortunately, this code:

```
df.to_csv(r'C:/Users/my/path/to/file.csv', index=FALSE, encoding='utf-8')
```

Gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm working in a jupyter notebook on a mac in case that's important. Sorry for such a noob question, I know this should be super easy

I googled similar issues where attribute so-and-so is missing, but none of the ones I found helped my problem

Comment: print(type(df)) is it a DataFrame?

Comment: @JasonBaker I sure hope so! it returns: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>